# RabbitMQ Java Client - Java Dependencies (standard libraries?)

Tags: java, rabbitmq, kettle

I need to integrate RabbitMQ with another system that runs on Java. So I went to the [official website](http://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html), downloaded the package and copied it to my classpath. Then I followed the [basic tutorial](http://neopatel.blogspot.com.br/2009/08/rabbitmq-java-clients-for-beginners.html), and I verified that importing external libraries work.

The problem I face now is probably very easy to solve for a Java developer: which standard Java libraries do I have to import to make the following code work?

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
...
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
```

without running into import errors like this:

```
Line 51, Column 18: No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters "java.lang.String"; 
candidates are: "void com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.setPort(int)"
```

I tried things like these, but I have no idea how that works in Java, so I would like to have some clarification. For example, when should I use an asterisk?

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.String.*;
```

By the way, the system I am trying to integrate RabbitMQ with is Pentaho Data Integration (a.k.a. Kettle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get rid of your `java.lang` imports.

Second, call `setPort` with an `int` and not a `String` as described in the [API](http://www.rabbitmq.com/javadoc/com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory.html#setPort%28int%29).

Answer (score 0):

Just including the amqp-client-${version} jar in classpath should be sufficient. Astreix is used to import all classes from a package. Class names in java begins with a caps while package names are in small case. So, java.lang is a package and String is a class. By default all classes of java.lang package are imported in a Java program and you do not need to write `import java.lang.String; or import java.lang.*;`

Comment: Do you mean I should add it besides "rabbitmq-client.jar" (version 3.1.5)? When I read the [website] (http://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html) I thought it was included. By the way, I am quite sure that "rabbitmq-client.jar" is in the classpath, because if I take it out of it I get a different error: Imported class "com.rabbitmq.client.Connection" could not be loaded.