# How to run RabbitMQ Java receiver?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, receiver

**Context:**

My aim is to simply run a RabbitMQ receiver (in Java) that would accept and print the messages to the console.  I have another service that would be sending the messages to this receiver.  Everything happens with the default config (ports, localhost, etc.).

**Steps followed:**

1. I am trying to follow [this RabbitMQ tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html).
2. As mentioned towards the end of the tutorial, to compile the [Recv.java](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/java/Recv.java) application, I run the following command (similar to the one given): 
    `javac -cp amqp-client-5.5.1.jar Recv.java`
3. Note that I manually downloaded the `amqp-client-5.5.1.jar` file and have copied it to `/Library/Java/Extensions` as mentioned in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675765/adding-to-the-classpath-on-osx).

**Error:**

When I try to run my application, I get many errors like below:

> Recv.java:1: error: package com.rabbitmq.client does not exist
>   import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
>   //------------------------^
>   Recv.java:2: error: package com.rabbitmq.client does not exist
>   import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
>   //------------------------^
>   Recv.java:3: error: package com.rabbitmq.client does not exist
>   import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
>   //------------------------^
>   Recv.java:4: error: package com.rabbitmq.client does not exist
>   import com.rabbitmq.client.DeliverCallback;
>   ...

Obviously, it is unable to find the packages to run.  However, the tutorial does not elaborate much and so I am unable to proceed.  I tried running the [RabbitMQ Java client](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client), but its `README.md` does not have how to run instructions either.  Oh, there was one other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406864/rabbitmq-java-client-java-dependencies-standard-libraries) which talked about some `rabbitmq-client.jar` file, but that is not mentioned anywhere in the tutorial or the README.md, so I am not sure I that answer was helpful.

How could I run this?

Comment: How do you run your application? Do you include `amqp-client-5.5.1.jar` on the classpath?

Comment: @LutzHorn, as mentioned in point 3, I have included it in `/Library/Java/Extensions` (which means the classpath) as per the linked SO answer.

Comment: Did you manage to run this ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the JAR to the classpath. If the `target/` folder contains the `Recv.class` file, do this:

```
$ javac -cp amqp-client-5.5.1.jar:target Recv
```

Comment: So as per my comment below the question, I have added the .jar file to the classpath. However I am unable to see any .class file in the target/ folder. So how do I run the command? Alternatively, could you please let me know how to run the rabbiqmq-java-client (because the README.MD file does not have any instructions about how to run it).